# Инициализирующий запрос данных с севера в react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch

При первом входе пользователя на страницу нужно отображать данные, из того что я прочитал, лучшее место для выборки начальных данных - это запрос еще до описания корневого компонента App.

```
import fetchIndexData from "./api/axios/fetchIndexData";
store.dispatch(fetchIndexData());

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <Provider store={store}>
              <... тут роутинг и все такое>
           </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Потом по идее данные попадают в компонент Promo, он отображается первым и опирается на эти самые данные, выводя их в цикле (там приходит массив с товарами). Но при данном способе ответ от сервера все равно не успевает прийти, и первый раз компонент выдает ошибку про undefined в props. Я решил это defaultProps-заглушкой, компонент вхолостую прогоняет пустой массив, на секунду отрисовывая полупустой компонент, потом приходит ответ от сервера и нормальные props - они и выводятся уже в цикле.

```
class Promo extends Component {

    static defaultProps = {
        initialListOfProducts: { data: [] }
    };

    render() {

        const { data } = this.props.initialListOfProducts;
        return (
            <section>
                    <ul>
                        {data.map(item => {
                            return (
                                <ProductCard key={item.id} item={item}/>
                            )
                        })}
                    </ul>
            </section>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        initialListOfProducts: state.db.initialListOfProducts,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        fetchIndexData: () => {
            dispatch(api.fetchIndexData());
        },
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Promo);
```

> Вопрос: есть ли способ как-то удобнее получать данные от сервера при
> первой отрисовке сайта, чтобы не выполнять этот первый асинхронный запрос, а сразу иметь инициализирующей данные? Или тут только такой вариант или просто спиннер
> какой-нибудь показывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать проверку в отрисовке (render) и вернуть null, когда данных нет. Компонент не будет отрисован.

При получении данных с сервера они будут отображены как вам надо.

```
class Promo extends Component {

    static defaultProps = {
        products: []
    };

    render() {
        if (!(this.props.products && this.props.products.length)) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <section>
                    <ul>
                        {this.props.products.map(item => {
                            return (
                                <ProductCard key={item.id} item={item}/>
                            )
                        })}
                    </ul>
            </section>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        products: state.db.products,
    }
}
```

Не передавайте данные компоненту, которые он не использует, иначе он будет бесполезно перерисовываться.